# Java 2D PNG: Calculate Dimension

Tags: java, 2d, bufferedimage, fontmetrics

I want to create a PNG Image with Java. In this image I want to show some random Text.
Normaly I would create a picture like this:

```
BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(300,300,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
bi.getGraphics().drawString("Hello world", 0, 0);
ImageIO.write(bi, "png", File.createTempFile("out", ".png"));
```

I know that I can calculate the String length with the following code:

```
bi.getGraphics().getFontMetrics().stringWidth("Hello world");
```

But to execute this, I need a Graphics Object (which I grab from the BufferedImage). So I must declare BufferedImage before I can use stringWidth.

The result is, that the image is much bigger than needed.

The only way I see is to create a "dummy BufferedImage". So I can calculate the needed width & height and after that I can create a BufferedImage that fit.

I can't find a better solution, but maybe someone can help me.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, in a hurry, but consider this test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Font font = Font.decode(Font.MONOSPACED);

    Rectangle2D bounds;
    String str = "Hello World";

    BufferedImage dummy = new BufferedImage(1, 1, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

    FontRenderContext context = new FontRenderContext(new AffineTransform(), true, true);
    bounds = font.getStringBounds(str, context);
    System.err.println("bounds: " + bounds);

    bounds = font.getStringBounds(str, dummy.createGraphics().getFontRenderContext());
    System.err.println("bounds: " + bounds);

    Graphics2D graphics = dummy.createGraphics();
    FontMetrics fontMetrics = graphics.getFontMetrics(font);
    bounds = fontMetrics.getStringBounds(str, graphics);
    System.err.println("bounds: " + bounds);
}
```

Output:

```
bounds: java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D$Float[x=0.0,y=-12.064453,w=79.21289,h=15.667969]
bounds: java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D$Float[x=0.0,y=-12.064453,w=77.0,h=15.667969]
bounds: java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D$Float[x=0.0,y=-12.064453,w=77.0,h=15.667969]
```

So it seems that just creating a dummy is most likely to get the desired result (the docs also states that creating a `FontRenderContext` might give unexpected/undefined results).